# How to copy some of column in another table without writing column name if it is sequence order in hive

Tags: hive

I have one table that contains for example 10 columns and I have to copy some of them to another table and add some more columns by default value or variable value. So there is any query that can do this by not writing all the column name again.

For example

`table 1 contain A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K` columns

`table 2 contain C,D,E,F,G,H,when ..., current_timestamp ,...etc` columns

How can I copy `C to H` column in the second table? Is there any UDF available or not?